# sp_executesql OUTPUT returning null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

**Question**: OUTPUT variable in the following code is always null despite the fact that the dynamic SQL executes successfully and shows the correct result in `SSMS` (as shown in the image below). What could be the issue and how can we fix it?

**Remark**: Online search shows multiple posts (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75833454/1232087) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29964539/1232087)). But they seem to have special cases (special characters etc.). But following example does not have any such special case, and I'm not sure what is the issue here.

```
--create table testTable(mycol varchar(10))
--insert #testTable values ('abc'), ('xy4z')
--select * from testTable
---------------------
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(150)
SET @tableName = 'testTable'
DECLARE @ColName NVARCHAR(150)
SET @ColName = 'mycol'
DECLARE @colMaxLen TINYINT

SET @sqlCommand = CONCAT(N'SELECT MAX(LEN(', @ColName, ')) FROM ', @tableName)
select @sqlCommand
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@tableName NVARCHAR(150), @ColName NVARCHAR(150), @colMaxLen TINYINT OUTPUT', @tableName = @tableName, @ColName = @ColName, @colMaxLen = @colMaxLen OUTPUT
SELECT @colMaxLen
```

[image]

Comment: you did not assign the variable `@colMaxLen` to the expression `MAX(LEN....` at all in your dynamic query

Comment: @Squirrel Your suggestion worked (thank you). For the benefit of other readers, you may want to convert you comment to a response with a brief detail, and I'll mark it as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not assign the variable @colMaxLen to the expression MAX(LEN.... at all in your dynamic query.

To do that, change the following

```
SET @sqlCommand = CONCAT(N'SELECT @colMaxLen = MAX(LEN(', @ColName, ')) FROM ', @tableName)
```